# PLAB 2 Business Visitor Visa - Sponsor related question

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

My brother in law who is a UK citizen has agreed to provide sponsorship for me and has provided me with a letter clarifying this and a photocopy of his British passport. However, due to confidentiality matter he will email visa section directly to provide with a copy of his bank statement.

Is it possible for the process to go this way or do I have to have all documents with me in person at my appointment?

Comment: Even if it were possible administratively, I can imagine an ECO will think, "if your brother-in-law distrusts you enough that he won't let you forward a bank statement, why on earth would he give you money? Something is fishy here." You don't want the ECO to think something is fishy.